# AngularJS ng-click not firing after compile attempt

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a template for my directive, which contains a scope variable called `content`:

```
<div class="directive-view">
    <span class="directive-header">My Directive</span>
    <span ng-bind-html="content"></span>
</div>
```

I have the following directive, which watches for changes to `content` and then compiles the element's contents:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('myApp.myDirective', [])
        .directive("myDirective", myDirective);

    function myDirective($compile, $sce) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
            },
            templateUrl:'../partials/directives/my-directive.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.testAlert = function(msg) { alert(msg) };
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

                scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml('Initial value');

                scope.$watch(attrs.content, function(value) {
                    element.html(value);
                    console.log("Content changed -- recompiling");
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                });

                scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml('<button ng-click="testAlert(\'clicked!\')">Click</button>');
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

The directive renders the `button` element. However, the controller function `testAlert()` does not get called when the `button` element is clicked on.

Also, the `$watch` callback is called only once, after `content` is set to `Initial value`. The callback is not triggered after `content` is set to the button. (I would have thought that the callback is triggered when the value of `attrs.content` is changed.)

If I manually recompile the element:

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

the `button` element still does not trigger the `testAlert` function when clicked.

How do I correctly recompile the element contents, so that the correct bindings are made?

Comment: You `$watch` function watch on change `attrs.content`. And you change `scope.content`. Try this `scope.$watch('content',function(){});`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko one as the same thing, `attrs.content` will get value as `content`, it will not make any difference

Comment: It's make difference! See my answer. Trying change `scope.$watch('content',...)` on `scope.$watch(attrs.content,...)` and you will see that it make difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need use `$sce` in this case. Use just `$compile`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/u511juwj/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
  $scope.changeTEmplate = function(){
      $scope.cont = '<div><b>i\'m changed</b></div>';
    }
  })
  .directive("myDirective", function myDirective($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {content:"="},
      template: `<div class="directive-view">
    <span class="directive-header">My Directive</span>
    <span></span>
    </div>`,
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.testAlert = function(msg) {
          alert(msg)
        };
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch('content', function(value) {
          var span = angular.element(element.find('span')[1]);
          span.html(value);
          console.log("Content changed -- recompiling",value);
            $compile(span)(scope);
        });
        scope.content = '<button ng-click="testAlert(\'clicked!\')">Click</button>';
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}!
    <button ng-click="changeTEmplate()"> change Content</button>
    <my-directive content="cont"></my-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```